# What exactly goes into MS by Research?

Tags: research-process, thesis

I recently gave a entrance exam for a graduate program, MS (by course) in computer science. Since I did well in exam, now I am being offered for MS by research. In first semester I can attend 3-4 subjects, at the end of my semester I have to chose my research area and a adviser. I do not have prior research experience nor have published any papers, so I believe it is a wonderful opportunity for me to get into research.

My question is, what exactly constitutes an MS by Research? What are my responsibilities? What should be my minimum contribution for thesis to graduate?

Comment: related http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/what-is-the-minimum-contribution-expected-from-msc-thesis

Comment: @seteropere: Good catch. Indeed, I'd be inclined to close this question as already answered (i.e. duplicate).